# right setting of testset at PredictorMeasurements

Tags: machine-learning

i am trying to write a code based on `Predict`, which does the following:

1. import some external data
2. define Predict on those data (setting of training and test data)
3. define PredictorMeasurements (setting of testset data)
4. define a function, which based on points 2 and 3, can make a predictive trend as a function of
   time
5. plot the function at number 4

Here some parts of the code:

```
    data1 = Dataset[data[[1]][[All, {2, 6}]]];
    {test1, training1} = TakeDrop[data1[[All, {1, 2}]], 100];
    testSet1 = {Normal[#[[]]] -> Normal[#[[2]]]} & /@ test1
    RandomSample[testSet1, 1]
    pm1 = PredictorMeasurements[p1, 
    testSet1, {"ComparisonPlot", "ResidualPlot", "ResidualHistogram", 
   "StandardDeviation"}]
```

unfortunately i am stuck at point 3 and get the following error message:

```
PredictorMeasurements::bdfmt: Argument Dataset [<<100>>] should be a rule or a list of rules.
```

i have tried to define testSet1 in every possible way, but i always get an error message.
Do you have any idea of where the problem is?

thanks

Comment: As I understand it, `testset` should be a plain list of rules. What is the format of testset in your code? It would be helpful if you could show its contents from your current code.

Comment: testSet1 = {Normal[#[[]]] -> Normal[#[[2]]]} & /@ test1                                                                 i can't paste the whole output of testSet1 (it is very long) but it looks like this: {DateObject[], 71.}-> 71., {DateObject[], 69.}-> 69., {DateObject[], 70.}-> 70.,

Comment: What is `p1`? From the error message, it seems like `testSet1` is a `Dataset`, not a list. Also, you should `RandomSample` the data before the test/train split.

Comment: p1 = Predict[training1 -> training1[[All, 2]], 
  Method -> "GradientBoostedTrees"]
 i tried to convert Dataset simple to List with the following: data1 = data[[1]][[All, {2, 6}]];  ut i still get this error message   PredictorMeasurements::bdfmt: Argument {{{Date,Hardness [N]}->Hardness [N]},{{{DateObject[{2004,6,28,0,0,0.},Instant,Gregorian,1.],70.}->70.},{{DateObject[{2004,6,28,0,0,0.},Instant,Gregorian,1.],71.}->71.},<<50>>} should be a rule or a list of rules.    do you know how i can fix this  thanks

Comment: i was finally able to get the code working , here it is :   


`data=Import@; data0 = data[[1]][[All, {2, 6}]];
data1 = Rest[data0];
{test1, training1} = TakeDrop[data1[[All, {1, 2}]], 100];
p1 = Predict[training1[[All, 1]] -> training1[[All, 2]], 
   Method -> "GradientBoostedTrees"];
testSet1 = test1[[All, 1]] -> test1[[All, 2]];
pm1 = PredictorMeasurements[p1, 
  testSet1, {"ComparisonPlot", "ResidualPlot", "ResidualHistogram", 
   "StandardDeviation"}]
Information[p1, "MethodOption"]
p1[DateObject[]]`
interesting, the best prediction are achieved by using GradientBoostedTrees